# How to run ffmpeg on heroku-18 stack?

Tags: heroku, ffmpeg

I have a Java web app on Heroku. It's on heroku-18 stack with heroku/java buildpack.

I need to compress some videos and due to the lack of such libraries for Java decided to install FFmpeg on Heroku.

Adding FFmpeg buildpacks like `https://github.com/kontentcore/heroku-buildpack-ffmpeg`, `https://github.com/jonathanong/heroku-buildpack-ffmpeg-latest` was successful as FFmpeg was installed but they failed when running because of various linking problems.
For that I tried to add `heroku-community/apt` buildstack. My Aptfile file contains just the `ffmpeg` package.

Still I'm getting
`ffmpeg: error while loading shared libraries: libpulsecommon-11.1.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

FFmpeg command that I try to run from the Java code is simple:
`ffmpeg -i video.webm video-compressed.webm`

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is quite outdated, but for me [this buildpack](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/jonathanong/heroku-buildpack-ffmpeg-latest) did the trick.

1. You don't need an Aptfile anymore
2. Make sure add this buildpack on top of all the others using `heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 https://github.com/jonathanong/heroku-buildpack-ffmpeg-latest.git`
3. Rebuild and deploy your app and the trick should be done.

Comment: Actually, I used the same solution but forgot to mention it here.